# Peer to peer replication of local databases

Tags: c, replication

I have a program in C that monitors traffic and records the URLs visited by the user. Currently, I am maintaining this in a hash table. My key is the src-IP address and the result is a data-structure with a linked list of URLs. I am currently maintaining 50k to 100k records in a hash table. When the user logs out, the record can get deleted.

The program independently runs on a Active-Standby pair. I want to replicate this database to another machine in case my primary machine crashes (the 2 systems act as Client and Server) and continue recording stuff associated with the user.

The hard way is to write code for sending this information to the peer and on the peer system to receive and store. The issue is, it will add lots of code (and bugs!). To do data-replication and data-store, here are a few prereqs:

- I want data-record replication between these machines. I am NOT looking at adding another machine/cluster unless required.
- Prefer library so that query is quick. If not another process on the same machine to which I can IPC.
- Add, update and delete operations should be supported.
- In memory database a must.
- Support multiple such databases with different keys.
- Something that has publish/subscribe.
- Resync capability if the backup dies and comes back again.
- Interface should be in C

Possible options I looked at were zookeeper, redis, memcached, sql-lite, berkeley-db.

- Zookeeper - Needs odd number of systems for tie-break. Not suitable for 1 to 1.
- Redis - Looks to fit my requirements with hiredis for C interface. Separate process though.
- Memcached - I don't have any caching requirements.
- Sql-lite - Embedded database with C interface
- Berkeley-DB - Embedded database for better scale.

So, Redis, Sql-lite and Berkeley-DB look like my options to go forward. Appreciate any help/thoughts on the DBs I should research more for my requirements. Or if there are any other DBs I should research? I apologize if my question is very generic. If the question does not belong here, please point me to the right forum.

Comment: While a good question, the key phrase here is "I am looking for suggestions for libraries" which unfortunately means that the question is off-topic for SO. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. I modified my question to list the options that I have looked for. If its generic, please point me the right forum to help me get started.